# Run downloaded Atom exe and see this page

Tags: atom-editor

I installed and used Atom happily for 3 months. One day, I decided to mess around with windows 10 environment variables , so I can make sure I added atom to the path, so I can open it in hper terminal with just .atom...
Anyway, that is not import to me, since then, every time I opened Atom, it shows me this page. I tried to uninstall atom and reinstall, but the result same, show me this red page. Also, I went to delete the path I added in the window environment variables about atom, but nothing works !!!
I really enjoy using atom. I hope someone here genius can help me. I used windows 10 and every else in my pc are working the same, except Atom.

Here is the code:

```
electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:15 (electron) crashReporter.start is deprecated in the renderer process. Call it from the main process instead.
log @ electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:15
C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app.asar\src\text-editor-element.js:357 [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020. Please use window.customElements.define instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade for more details.
index.js:129 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Honeybear\.atom\compile-cache\less\40e22529c8729b65e1d700a7ae3f73d57ed1288f\imports.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1265:35)
    at Proxy.writeFileSync (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:271609)
    at LessCache.writeJson (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:14:1222002)
    at LessCache.setImportPaths (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:14:1221197)
    at new LessCache (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:14:1219647)
    at new LessCompileCache (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:14:13882)
    at ThemeManager.loadLessStylesheet (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:393667)
    at ThemeManager.loadStylesheet (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:393553)
    at ThemeManager.requireStylesheet (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:391667)
    at ThemeManager.reloadBaseStylesheets (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:393188)
    at ThemeManager.loadBaseStylesheets (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:393135)
    at AtomEnvironment.initialize (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:813556)
    at t.exports (C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.58.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:806617)
    at setupWindow (file:///C:/Users/Honey%20Bear/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.58.0/resources/app.asar/static/index.js:175:12)
    at window.onload (file:///C:/Users/Honey%20Bear/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.58.0/resources/app.asar/static/index.js:106:9)
handleSetupError @ index.js:129
```

[problem_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seYry.jpg)[problem_pic_red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAvBH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] the question to give it a more specific title.

Comment: Have you tried undoing your changes to the environment variables? What changes did you make exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "every else"? "every**thing** else"?

Comment: If it helps, I Googled the error message and found [what seems to be the source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/refs/heads/chromium/4466/front_end/i18n/locales/en-US.json#5615)

Comment: Try reinstalling. Again. With a fresh new installer.

Comment: Not sure about Windows, but under Linux atom caches a whole lot of things that don't get deleted when you uninstall. It looks like that cache may live in `C:\Users\Honeybear\AppData\Local\atom` under Windows, which would make sense. Try deleting that folder and then start atom.

Answer (score 0):

`EPERM` is a permission error... and reinstalling Atom might not be the answer, because it may leave this one problematic directory underneath the user-profile behind (at least on Linux this is quite the default outcome). Rather go to `C:\Users\Honeybear` and take ownership of directory `.atom` there - or use the command-line for that: `takeown /F C:\Users\Honeybear\.atom`.
That directory might be hidden by default, unless "show hidden files" is enabled in the Explorer.

Deleting that directory or moving it out of the way would be the other option, which has one side-effect: the current user's IDE settings would be lost (which eventually may or may not be an issue). If deleting something, I'd try the compile cache first: `C:\Users\Honeybear\.atom\compile-cache`.

Comment: When I open file location after click Atom short cut,  Target: "C:\Users\honeybear\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe"  ;